# Go: compare two time structs considering only the dates

Tags: date, go, time

I'm looking for a clean way to do this in go:

```
package main 

import(
    "fmt"
    t "time"
)

func isSameDate() bool {
    timeA, err := t.Parse("01022006 15:04", "08152016 09:00")
    timeB, err := t.Parse("01022006 15:04", "08152016 07:30")

    return timeA.Date == timeB.Date // This is C# code but I'm looking for something similar in GO
}
```

Should return true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the [`Truncate` function](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Truncate) from the time package you can cut it down to the date.

So truncate both times with the parameter `24 * time.Hour` to get the date of each and compare with the [`Equal` function](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Equal).

```
timeA, _ := t.Parse("01022006 15:04", "08152016 09:00")
timeB, _ := t.Parse("01022006 15:04", "08152016 07:30")
return timeA.Truncate(24 * time.Hour).Equal(timeB.Truncate(24*time.Hour))
```

Here's the sample: https://play.golang.org/p/39ws4DL2pB

Answer (score 1):

Could call `timeA.Date()` format that to a string and compare them like in the following example.  Don't know if there's a better way.

```
func isSameDate() bool {
    timeA, _ := t.Parse("01022006 15:04", "08152016 09:00")
    timeB, _ := t.Parse("01022006 15:04", "08152016 07:30")

    ay, am, ad := timeA.Date()
    a := fmt.Sprintf("%d%d%d", ay, am, ad)

    by, bm, bd := timeB.Date()
    b := fmt.Sprintf("%d%d%d", by, bm, bd)
    return a == b
}
```

Comment: @RAFJR look at Verrans answer above. That's the correct way.